# Ubuntu network plummet during snap install

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and there is no network issue on Windows. This happens on both Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS that I have tried (currently on 18.04).

The connection fails whenever I try to install anything through snap or the Ubuntu Software app. The connection is stable during web browsing but seems to also break during online speed tests and downloading large files. Once the internet got disconnected, I had to turn the Wi-Fi setting off and on again to regain connection.

Solutions I have tried:

1. Disable wifi power management [Ubuntu 20.04 Network Performance Extremely Slow](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230525/1088171)
2. Remove iwlwifi package https://askubuntu.com/a/1231662/1088171
3. Disable 802.11n https://askubuntu.com/a/1037623
4. Change REGDOMAIN country code https://askubuntu.com/a/1088379
5. Configure Atheros nohwcrypt https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/
6. IPv4 priority https://askubuntu.com/a/790022/1088171